# How can we publish an artifact to a local Ivy repository in Gradle?

Tags: ivy, gradle

In Gradle, we have configured a local maven repository, and artifacts are uploaded there for use in my local builds of other projects.

I'd prefer to use an Ivy repository (so I can have a custom pattern for artifact names).

How do you configure Gradle to upload to a local Ivy repository?

Comment: This helped me: http://blog.anthavio.net/2016/06/maven-sbt-gradle-local-repository.html

Answer (score 7):

Try this (based on [this](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#publishIvyRepository) and the [API](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/IvyArtifactRepository.html)):

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        ivy {
            ivyPattern "/home/robin/.ivy2/local/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivys/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"
            artifactPattern "/home/robin/.ivy2/local/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[ext]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"
        }
    }
}
```

(replacing those patterns with your real ivy/artifact patterns).